# Adding a type before an existing parameter name auto-deletes the name in VS2013; how to disable this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013. Previously if I had a line of code like this:

```
void foo(const char *s) { ... }
```

I could select the "`const char *`" and type "`std::string` *`<space>`*" to end up with:

```
void foo(std::string s) { ... }
```

But now when I press the spacebar, the name "`s`" disappears:

```
void foo(std::string ) { ... }
```

I think this is related to the auto-complete feature, since after the "`std::`" is complete, it starts prompting me with names in the `std::` namespace. Typing "`std::string` *`<Esc> <space>`*" avoids this issue, but that's an extra keypress which isn't habitual for me. I don't want to disable autocomplete entirely, just make it stop removing variable names.